# Qt5 - copy additional files on build time - must work in many situations

Tags: qt, qmake

In my C++/Qt5 project, I've got some external files (PNGs and so on) which I need to have copied beside the executable on build time. I found no good way so far to realize that with qmake.

I asked a lighter variant of this question years ago, but everything there and everything I found on the Internet appears incomplete to me. It must work in each of the following conditions:

- Somebody picks my sourcecode and just calls `qmake foo.pro && make && ./foo` (on Linux)
- Like above, but she also calls `make install` afterwards
- Like the first one, but with Windows (forget about Qt DLLs or other external stuff - I ask just about my own files)
- Somebody picks my sourcecode, opens it in QtCreator and just clicks on Play (on any OS - but, ehmm, lets say at least Linux and Windows)

All I currently have is rather technical and broken as well. There must be something more lightweight and better working than mine?

This is a stripped-down variant which describes what my `foo.pro` does:

```
QT += core gui xml widgets
TARGET = foo
TEMPLATE = app
...
EXTRA_BINFILES += logo.png
for(FILE, EXTRA_BINFILES) {
    extrafiles.commands += $$quote($${QMAKE_COPY} $$shell_path($${PWD}/$${FILE}) $$shell_path($${OUT_PWD})$$escape_expand(\n\t))
}
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += extrafiles
POST_TARGETDEPS += extrafiles
```

It looks much more complicated that it should to me. It is broken in many regards. E.g. if fails in the very first condition (since it tries to copy the file to itself). With a hotfix in place, it again fails on Windows (since `OUT_PWD` is not the real target, but `OUT_PWD/debug` or `/release` is). I suspect, `make install` wouldn't work either (but; untested).

Please help ;) Do I really have to add fixes for all that, or is there a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

Using shell/qmake scripts before the build starts in your PRO file:

`QMAKE_PRE_LINK += someShellCommand $$system_quote($$shell_quote(somePath)) $$escape_expand(\\n\\t)`

For example,

```
win32 { 
QMAKE_PRE_LINK += copy /Y $$system_quote($$shell_quote($${PWD}/../../images/*.png)) $$system_quote($$shell_quote($${PWD}/../build/Output/release/resources)) $$escape_expand(\\n\\t)
}


linux { 
QMAKE_PRE_LINK += cp -r -t -f $$system_quote($$shell_quote($${PWD}/../../images/*.png)) $$system_quote($$shell_quote($${PWD}/../build/Output/release/resources)) $$escape_expand(\\n\\t)
}
```

Using shell/qmake scripts at build-time completion in your PRO file:

`QMAKE_POST_LINK += someShellCommand $$system_quote($$shell_quote(somePath)) $$escape_expand(\\n\\t)`

Comment: Hi. I'm not 100% sure, but for me it looks just like a subtly different variant of mine, which does essentially the same. Isn't it? My current solution uses shell commands (although they are somewhat conceiled behind cross-platform stuff). But this seems a bit too low-level for covering all typical situations elegantly.